# Define one notify block for several tasks in Ansible

Tags: ansible

Is it possible to define one `notify` block for several tasks?

In next code snippet `notify: restart tomcat` defined 3 times, but I want to define it only one time and "apply" to list of tasks

```
- name : template context.xml
  template:
    src: context.xml.j2
    dest: /usr/share/tomcat/conf/context.xml
    group: tomcat
    mode: 0664
  notify: restart tomcat

- name : copy server.xml
  copy:
    src: server.xml
    dest: /etc/tomcat/server.xml
    group: tomcat
    mode: 0664
  notify: restart tomcat

- name : copy atomikos-integration-extension
  copy:
    src: atomikos-integration-extension-3.7.1-20120529.jar
    dest: /usr/share/tomcat/ext-libs/
    group: tomcat
    mode: 0664
  notify: restart tomcat
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like already mentioned above it is now possible to use notify on a block.
Just make sure not to forget your handler.

```
- block:
  - name : template context.xml
    template:
      src: context.xml.j2
      dest: /usr/share/tomcat/conf/context.xml
      group: tomcat
      mode: 0664
  - name : copy server.xml
    copy:
      src: server.xml
      dest: /etc/tomcat/server.xml
      group: tomcat
      mode: 0664
  - name : copy atomikos-integration-extension
    copy:
      src: atomikos-integration-extension-3.7.1-20120529.jar
      dest: /usr/share/tomcat/ext-libs/
      group: tomcat
      mode: 0664
  notify: restart tomcat
```

Answer (score 19):

No, you cannot.

Notify sets a trigger to run the specified handler based on the status of the task. There is no "status for a block of tasks" in Ansible hence you cannot define `notify` for a block.

Besides, it wouldn't change anything functionally, only influence the visual appeal (and I would claim by obscuring things rather than simplifying). The handler is run only once regardless of how many tasks triggered it.

Comment: Well, I understand that if any of the tasks changed, then the block changed. Is a pity that ansible doesn't support this

Comment: It is now possible, see https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/73572/commits - as of Ansible v2.11

Specifically this commit details testing the change for blocks https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/73572/commits/899f39800cb74e0e38010aba30087672819b2097

Answer (score 7):

As of Ansible v2.11 (https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blame/stable-2.11/changelogs/CHANGELOG-v2.11.rst#L599)

It is now possible to set notify on a block, and import_tasks https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/73572/commits/899f39800cb74e0e38010aba30087672819b2097

So, wrap your tasks with a block and set notify on the block!

Comment: I am trying to assign a notify to a block into a roles task and all I get is: `ERROR! 'notify' is not a valid attribute for a Block`

Answer (score -5):

A small workaround if you want to specifically want one handler for three tasks.

> In your main role

```
- include: role2.yml
```

> In role 2

```
- name : template context.xml
  template:
    src: context.xml.j2
    dest: /usr/share/tomcat/conf/context.xml
    group: tomcat
    mode: 0664

- name : copy server.xml
  copy:
    src: server.xml
    dest: /etc/tomcat/server.xml
    group: tomcat
    mode: 0664

- name : copy atomikos-integration-extension
  copy:
    src: atomikos-integration-extension-3.7.1-20120529.jar
    dest: /usr/share/tomcat/ext-libs/
    group: tomcat
    mode: 0664

- name: running handler for above tasks
  debug: msg='running handler for all three'
  notify: restart tomcat
```

Comment: The handler will never run with this code. Including tasks will also do nothing. And don't use confusing names when explaining things - it has nothing to do with roles.

Comment: The idea of handlers is to notify from any task whose action requires the handler to run - e.g. changing a service's config or installing new service code requires a service restart.  This solution breaks that model.

Comment: agreed.. was just purposing a little hack, no offense