# Ansible: notify handler for block of multiple tasks

Tags: ansible

Rather than add a `notify:` statement to each task in a role, I'd like to have any of the tasks notify the handler on a change - something like this:

```yaml
block:    
- name: "001 | do something"
  debug: "blah"
- name: "002 | do something else"
  module: "blah"    
notify: "restart webserver"
```

However, Ansible reports that

```
notify is not a valid attribute for a block.
```

This would be really useful - and, I'd argue, more readable.   I want to restart the webserver if I changed the config, or if I installed a new module; upgraded some depending package, etc.

In response to a comment, I'm not asking for a block *in a* handler, but for a notify to apply to a block. Essentially, I want to notify a handler on any change made by any of the tasks in a role.  I take the point that blocks don't have a changed status, which explains why it doesn't work.   It'd be nice if the changed status *was inherited by the block* so that the handler could be notified at the task or the block level.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Block in Handler - Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71578834/using-block-in-handler-ansible). Ansible do not provide `block` functionality for `handlers`. Instead you could use an other approach and put the logic into a separate task file, so you have just one import task.

Comment: If you think about it in a broader way, you'd realise it does not really makes sense to apply a `notify` on a block because the block won't have a changed status, which is what will trigger the handler.

Comment: @U880D your proposed duplicate is the other way around, they want a `block` in an handler, when the OP here wants a `notify` on a `block`.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε, right. But still, instead of using a block, the logic could be imported (`import_tasks`) from a separate task list file. Than there is just one task in the role to add the `notify:` statement and no multiple.

Comment: @U880D that deserve an answer on its own then, not a duplicate closure :)

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε, agree. Since [handlers: running operations on change](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_handlers.html) one would need additionally to [define change](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#defining-changed) at [import a task list](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/import_tasks_module.html).

Comment: Thanks, @β.εηοιτ.βε - that does explain the why (and question edited to accept the point).

Comment: @U880D I'm confused - the include_tasks docs here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_tasks_module.html  seem to imply that include_tasks doesn't have a notify attribute (I'm going to try that anyway in case I've misread).   Any chance you could elaborate on your comment (and remove the duplicate flag)? Thanks

Comment: Mhm, what is you Ansible version BTW? https://stackoverflow.com/a/67600009/2123530

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε, sure, I've removed the duplicate and crafted an answer after further research and looking up references. Now it should be clarified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According [Playbook Keywords](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#block), above Ansible v2.9 a `block` can use

> `notify` List of handlers to notify when the task returns a `changed=True` status.

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - block:

    - name: Show message
      shell:
        cmd: 'echo "Hello."'
      changed_when: true

    notify: hanlder

  handlers:

  - name: handler
    debug:
      msg: "Here I am."
```

**Further Q&A**

- [It is now possible to set notify on a `block`, and `import_tasks`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67600009/6771046)

**Further References**

- [Block of `include_tasks` with handler/notify](https://groups.google.com/g/ansible-project/c/McuizSFnTCc)
- Ansible Issue #[64935](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/64935)
- Ansible Pull #[73572](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/73572/)

Comment: Thank you.  Of course, we're on Ansible 2.9.14.  :-(  I'll see if it can be upgraded.

Comment: The docs for handlers do indeed convey the information as you suggest - but refer to 2.9 for RedHat subscribers, which we are.  Frustrating.